# Get the first value of an Enum type in F#

Tags: f#

I have a class with an enum property. To use the compact property syntax I have to initialize it with a value from the type, eg.

```
type Color = 
    | Blue= 0
    | Green= 1

type MyClass() =
    member val Col = Color.Blue with get, set // <-- the problem
```

However, I don't like the hard coded `Blue` in there, and would prefer to set it to the first item of the enumeration.

I've been able to do it with this:

```
member val Color = enum<Color>(unbox (Enum.GetValues(typeof<Color>).GetValue(0))) ...
```

Needless to say, I'm hoping there's a better way to either get the first value of an enum, or initialize the property!

Comment: Is `member val Col = Unchecked.defaultOf<Color> with get, set` undesirable for some reason?

Comment: @ildjarn that looks OK, but it produces weird behaviour! The inferred type of the member `Col` is `Color` (which is what I want) but when I evaluate `MyClass().Col` it produces `val it : Color = 0` (should be `Blue`).

Comment: That sounds like an FSI problem - does the code compile and work correctly at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the two alternatives you mention, I believe you are better off with `Color.Blue`. While the numeric values backing the enumeration are entirely arbitrary, the colours at least have some meaning in your application. If you are uncomfortable with setting the value directly because there is extra meaning associated to the default you can always define it separately somewhere else:

```
let standardUniformColor = Color.Blue
//(...)
type MyClass() = member val Col = standardUniformColor with get, set
```

Comment: I tried something similar and hit the problem that the `standardUniformColor` must be declared in a module, while my type is declared in a namespace. Still, I agree that, in principle, yours is an improvement on `Color.Blue`.

Comment: You could make the default value a static member of your class, or of some other class, or add it to a module - whatever makes sense within your program.

Comment: I discovered that one can declare a module within a namespace, so I have `namespace Colors... type Color = .. module Values = let defaultColor = Color.Blue`. I can then refer to `Colors.Values.defaultColor`. I have accepted this answer as the safest and most general solution. One can use any of these three solutions, depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

If the first member is significant within your program then it makes sense to make it explicit. It's perfectly fine to have two members with the same value.

```
type Color    = 
    | Default = 0
    | Blue    = 0
    | Green   = 1

type MyClass() =
    member val Col = Color.Default with get, set
```

Since enum equality depends on the underlying value, this works as desired (i.e., prints `"blue"`):

```
let c = MyClass()
match c.Col with
| Color.Blue -> printfn "blue"
| _ -> printfn "not blue"
```

Comment: I like this very much. I was concerned that whenever the priority was used in a `match` function that one might be required to cover the `Default` case but that is not so - it doesn't show any warning. So the compiler seems to use the numeric values. The only limitation is that if one changes the enum values then one must change the default, however this is all in one place so it should be easy to see (....). In the answer I first accepted the hard coded value `0` is used in a different place from the definition.

Comment: I ran into a problem with this when I used it in my program, because I enumerate over the enum type with `for c in (Enum.GetValues(typeof<Color>)) do` and in this instance the compiler uses the symbols rather than the numeric values, ie. the loop is executed three times, and the values for `c` are `Blue`, `Blue`, `Green`. I eventually went with @duplode's solution below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the magic `enum` function like so:

```
type Color =
    | Blue= 0
    | Green= 1

type MyClass() =
    member val Col : Color = enum 0 with get, set
```

The only catch is that you need a type annotation somewhere so that the compiler knows which enum to cast to.

NOTE: This assumes that the enum's first value is 0.

Comment: For the type annotation I can use either `enum<Color> 0` or `enum 0 : Color`

Comment: NOTE: This answer assumes that the enum's first value is 0. I think that for the completely general case (eg `Blue = 10 | Green = 20`) one would have to use my long-winded expression. (confirmed with experiment).

Comment: I've decided that @Daniel's suggestion is better (for the reasons I state in the comment) so have changed it to the accepted answer. If anyone disagrees, then please feel free to object.